# Using Java Streams determine if subset of stream is over a threshold

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Is it possible to use streams to determine if a subset of that stream is greater than a threshold.

Lets say I have a list of of ages and I want to trigger a certain action if there are more than 10 ages above 20.

So far I have tried filtering (as that will give me the ages over 20), I can get a count out, which is fine as I can do a normal if check on the count, but I feel I should be able to go further and be more declarative.

Thanks
Gavin

Comment: Thanks for adding the appropriate tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a terminal operation such as `hasAtLeast(n)` for streams, but it's simple enough to achieve this behavior by combining some other operations.

Assuming stream is an IntStream (it's easy enough to give a similar solution for a Stream of Objects):

```
if (stream.filter(i -> i > 20).limit(11).count() > 10) {

}
```

While this is not very different from what you already tried, using `limit()` ensures that only enough elements of the stream would be evaluated before triggering the action.

Comment: Having just come up with a solution for objects in my domain, I don't think it adds any readability to your solution, perhaps that is why there isn't an `hasAtLeast(n)`.  Thank you.

Comment: @Eran wouldn't that apply the "action" only to the entries that are actually above 20? This is pure theoretical, but would there be a way to apply the "action" to the entire stream, if some part of a stream would match a condition?

Comment: @Eugene The condition already consumes the stream, so you'll have to create a new stream in order to apply the action, and you'll be able to decide on which elements to apply it then.

Comment: @Eran that's what I thought. Thx though.